# Questions in Theorem 6 of Chapter 6 of Hoffman Kunze Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-theory

While self studying Linear Algebra from Hoffman Kunze I am unable to understand some deductions in Theorem-6 on Page 204 .

Adding Image:[image]

> $(1)$ In 7th last line from below I am not able to deduce how $q- q(c_{j})$ equals $( x-c_{j} ) h$ despite the definition of $q$ being clear to me ( It's given in line above.

> $(2)$ How did in 3rd last line from below $p(T)\alpha=0$? And how does that implies the belonging of $q(T)\alpha$ in $W$? The equality of $p(T)\alpha = (T-c_{j}I ) q(T)\alpha$ is clear but I don't know how they became equal to $0$.

Kindly help.

Comment: I had the exact same question as your first one. I missed $c_j$ is a root of $q-q(c_j)$ polynomial. Following is easy to show: if $s$ is a constant polynomial over $F$ (i.e. $s=c\cdot x^0$, for some $c\in F$), then $s(\alpha)=c\cdot (\alpha )^0=c\cdot 1_V$. I suppose you have seen this thing, if not [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4532685/861687) is a recap. Since $q(c_j)$ is a constant polynomial (it is technically an element of $F$, we abuse notation), we have $[q(c_j)](c_j)=q(c_j)\cdot 1_F=q(c_j)$. So $[q-q(c_j)](c_j)=q(c_j)-q(c_j)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Of course, $c_j$ is a root of $q-q(c_j)$. Hence there is some polynomial $h$ such that $q-q(c_j) = (x-c_j)\cdot h$.

(2) Since $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$, one has $p(T) = 0$ by definition.

Moreover, $W$ was defined to be the span of all characteristic vectors of $T$. Here, one has $0 = (T-c_j I)q(T)\alpha$. In other words, $q(T)\alpha \in \mathrm{ker}(T-c_jI)$, which means that $q(T)\alpha$ is a characteristic vector of $T$ to the eigenvalue $c_j$ (or $q(T)\alpha = 0$).