# Applying polynomials to linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, definition

In the textbook that I am reading, the following is how a polynomial is applied to a linear map.

Definition: For a polynomial $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_nz^n$ and a linear map $T\in L(V, V)$, we define the polynomial $p(T)$ to be the polynomial $p(T)=a_0I+a_1T+\dots+a_nT^n$.

My question is: Can results regarding a polynomial $p(z)$ be interpreted to be the same as for the polynomial $p(T)$? For example, suppose that a polynomial $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_nz^n$ over $\Bbb{C}$ has a factorisation $$p(z)=c(z-\lambda_1)\cdots(z-\lambda_m)$$

Does the polynomial $p(T)$ also have a factorisation that mimics this factorisation? Something like $$p(T)=c(T-\lambda_1I)\cdots(T-\lambda_mI)$$

I should also add that polynomials were defined to be functions $p : F\to F$ where $F$ denotes the field of real or complex numbers.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165539/factoring-a-matrix-polynomial Does this help?

Comment: @jcneek It doesn't answer my question. Even the answer to that question says that they don't know how to answer the second question, which is my example in this question. Can a factorisation of a polynomial be considered as a factorisation for the polynomial of the linear map.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882069/why-does-polynomial-factorization-generalize-to-matrices

Comment: @jcneek Thanks, didn't think about multiplying the factored form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the operators $T\in L(V,V)$ are linear, then yes, the factorization is valid. That's because you can just multiply out $c(T-\lambda_1 I)\cdots(T-\lambda_m I)$ and you get the same polynomial $p(T)$ as before based on how $c$ and the $\lambda_i$ combine to form the coefficients $a_k$.

As for the definition: You say that $p:F\rightarrow F$ is how the polynomial is defined. What we are doing when we are writing $p(T)$ is that we are saying "Well, we know what that polynomial is based on $F$. Let us *extend* it to other kinds of objects by *defining* $p(T)$ as a polynomial on operators". It is, strictly speaking, not the *same* function as the original polynomial because it has a different domain. Rather, given a polynomial $p=p_F$, we have defined a different function $p_{L(V,V)}$ by using the same polynomial coefficients as $p_F$ has. We just find it *convenient* to use the same symbol, even though it really is a different function.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about multiplying the factored form.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(V,F,+,\cdot)$ be a vector space over $F$. $(V,F,+,\cdot,\times)$ is **linear algebra over $F$** if $\times:V\times V\to V$ have following properties:

$(1)$ $\alpha \times (\beta \times \gamma)$ $=(\alpha \times \beta)\times \gamma$, for all $\alpha, \beta, \gamma\in V$

$(2)$ $\alpha \times (\beta+\gamma)$ $=\alpha \times \beta + \alpha \times \gamma$ and $(\alpha +\beta)\times \gamma$ $=\alpha \times \gamma +\beta \times \gamma$, for all $\alpha, \beta, \gamma\in V$

(3)  $c\cdot (\alpha \times \beta)$ $=(c\cdot \alpha)\times \beta$ $=\alpha \times (c\cdot \beta)$, for all $c\in F$.

If $\exists 1_V\in V$ such that $1_V \times \alpha$ $=\alpha \times 1_V$ $=\alpha$, for all $\alpha \in V$, then we say $(V,F,+,\cdot, \times)$ is **linear algebra with identity over $F$**.
If $\alpha \times \beta$ $=\beta \times \alpha$, for all $\alpha ,\beta \in V$, then we say $V$ is **commutative**.

> **Definition:** Let $V$ be a linear algebra with identity over $F$. Suppose $\alpha ^0=1_V$, $\forall \alpha\in V$. Define $F[x]\times V\to V$ such that $(p,\alpha)$ $=p(\alpha)$ $=\sum_{i=0}^na_i \cdot \alpha^i\in V$.

It’s easy to check $(L(V,V),F,+,\cdot ,\circ)$ is linear algebra with identity over $F$. By above definition $p(T)\in L(V,V)$. I don’t think it is accurate to say $p(T)$ is a “polynomial”.

Comment: Our primary motivation for defining linear algebra over $F$ was to make sense of $\alpha^i$.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn’t mean to write polynomial. $p(T)$ is really just an operator on $V$.